# Go - Concurrent merge sort hangs unless there is a fmt call in the base case

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

This is my attempt at a concurrent merge sort. I wrote and tested it non-concurrently first, so the problem is not to do with the merge sort logic, but something to do with how I am using goroutines/channels.

When I run the program, it hangs for several seconds and then gets signal: killed.

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
)

func merge(a []int, b []int) []int {
  var aCounter int = 0
  var bCounter int = 0

  var newArray []int = []int{}
  
  for aCounter < len(a) || bCounter < len(b) {
    if aCounter >= len(a) {
      newArray = append(newArray, b[bCounter])
      bCounter++
    } else if bCounter >= len(b) {
      newArray = append(newArray, a[aCounter])
      aCounter++
    } else {
      if a[aCounter] < b[bCounter] {
        newArray = append(newArray, a[aCounter])
        aCounter++
      } else {
        newArray = append(newArray, b[bCounter])
        bCounter++
      }
    }
  }

  return newArray
}

func mergeSort(arr []int, c chan []int) {
  if len(arr) == 1 {
    c <- arr
  }

  firstHalfChan := make(chan []int)
  secondHalfChan := make(chan []int)
  
  go mergeSort(arr[0:len(arr)/2], firstHalfChan)
  go mergeSort(arr[len(arr)/2:len(arr)], secondHalfChan)

  firstHalf, secondHalf := <-firstHalfChan, <-secondHalfChan

  c <- merge(firstHalf, secondHalf)
}

func main() {
  s := []int{10, 3, 8, 1, 2, 9}

  channel := make(chan []int)
  go mergeSort(s, channel)

  sorted := <- channel

  fmt.Println(sorted)
}
```

However, if I add a fmt call to the base case of the mergeSort, it will actually print all expected values and then print the correct result of the merge sort, and exit without error.

```
func mergeSort(arr []int, c chan []int) {
  if len(arr) == 1 {
    fmt.Println(arr) // ADDED
    
    c <- arr
  }

  firstHalfChan := make(chan []int)
  secondHalfChan := make(chan []int)
  
  go mergeSort(arr[0:len(arr)/2], firstHalfChan)
  go mergeSort(arr[len(arr)/2:len(arr)], secondHalfChan)

  firstHalf, secondHalf := <-firstHalfChan, <-secondHalfChan

  c <- merge(firstHalf, secondHalf)
}
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? And if I am doing something wrong, explain what it is?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that when I changed my code to use channels instead of returning values, I neglected to realize that it would now execute past the code that sends to a channel, unlike a return statement which stops code execution after that point in the function.

The fix was to add a return to the base case:

```
  if len(arr) <= 1 {
    c <- arr
    return
  }
```

The fmt statement "worked" because it added a delay to this call before spawning more goroutines endlessly, allowing the main thread to get its result and terminate before running out of memory.

EDIT: Also changed == to <= in order to catch the base case of empty array.